# Render a view in a json object

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm with Rails 4.
I'm trying to understand how to make my actions using ajax in my controller.

So I've created a method like that:

```
  def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params)
    if @client.save
      render :json => {:result => 'success' }
    else
      render :json => {:result => 'error', :template => (HERE MY PROBLEM) 'new' }
    end
  end
```

I want the function return a result state and in case there is a error, the view 'new'.

So, how can I inject a view generation as value of a json?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found that

```
render :json => {:result => 'error', :template => render_to_string('new', layout: false) }
```